# Putting elements between background and content on the site

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index, absolute

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.bg{
  background: green;
}
.header{
  height: 500px;
}
```

My goal: add elements(ellipses) behind the header's content by z axis. (see design photo)

[Design Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/933l9.png)

This ellipses should be positioned absolute

I tried to this:

```
<div class="bg">
        <div className="ellipse"></div>
        <div class="header">
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

Then, I positioned .ellipse absolute and gave it z-index: 0, and z-index:1 for .header. Actually, .ellipse is position: absolute, but .header is static. It didn't produce the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the position of the bg and header elements other then static to be able to use the z-index. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

I've also adjusted the code a bit to mach the image you provided.

```css
.bg {
      position: relative;
      background: #e2ede9;
    }

    .ellipse {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;   /* Adjust these values */
      left: -15%;  /* Adjust these values */
      width: 300px;  /* Or the desired size of your ellipse */
      height: 300px; /* Or the desired size of your ellipse */
      background: #cfe3dc; /* Or the desired color of your ellipse */
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 0;
      transform: translate(-10%, -10%); /* to center the ellipse */
    }

    .header {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      height: 500px;
      padding: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid adding additional `html` elements and use a radial gradient instead if the cirle is only decorational, for example:

```css
.header {
background: radial-gradient(30px circle at 50px 200px, 
                            #E71D36 50%, 
                            transparent 51%);
}
```

or multiple, devided by `,`:

```css
.header {
background: radial-gradient(50px circle at 100px 100px,
                              #FFFFFF 50%,
                              transparent 51%),
            radial-gradient(75px circle at 300px 400px,
                              #FD0000 50%,
                              transparent 51%);
}
```

For more information about this technique please see here: https://www.kirupa.com/css/circles_radial_gradient.htm